# Absolute Value inside an integral

Tags: integration, absolute-value

So I have that $|f(x) - h(x)| \le |f(x) - g(x)| + |g(x) - h(x)|$.

What I'm wondering is if this is the same as saying

$$\int_a^b |f(x) - h(x)|{\rm d}x \le \int_a^b |f(x) - g(x)|{\rm d}x + \int_a^b |g(x) - h(x)|{\rm d}x.$$

Is this valid?

Comment: It is valid as long as $g(x)$ is integralble on $[a,b]$.

Comment: It's not the same thing, but the first thing implies the second thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is triangle inequality evaluated in the integral from a to b.

It is posible thanks to the monotonic property of the integrals.

The only condition is that f,g,h must be integrable on [a,b], indeed continouos in (a,b) so the rest of them would be.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desigualdad_triangular#Generalizaci%C3%B3n_de_la_desigualdad_triangular

Comment: Monotonicity gives you that $f(x) \le g(x) \Rightarrow \int_a^b f(x)\ dx \le \int_a^b g(x)\ dx$, but how do you argue that $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx \le \int_a^b g(x)\ dx \Rightarrow f(x) \le g(x) $?

Comment: I thought he only wanted to solve the first implication.

Comment: I see. "Same thing as saying" usually means "if and only if", but if it's just the one direction that OP is looking for then I guess indeed we are done :)

Comment: @AlkaKadri If the second inequality holds for all choices of $a,b$ with $a<b$ then (assuming existence of the integrals) the first equality holds almost everywhere. So we can convert this into and iff statement.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Definitely. And if $f,g,h$ are continuous then it holds everywhere, but the individual that answered hasn't stated that so I was just trying to prompt him/OP to state why they think the converse is true.